# Send and Receive QStrings String through the Raspberry Pi serial port c++

Tags: c++, string, serial-port, raspberry-pi2, uart

I am trying to write a string command to the serial port of my Raspberry Pi 2 B without success. I followed this http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/programming-in-c/uart-serial-port/using-the-uart, but I need to send and receive QStrings (or arrays of bytes). Are there specific c++ functions that send and receive strings through the RPi Serial Port?
Could someone share some sample code?
Many thanks in advance!

Andrea

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [QString](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html) docs you will see a number of methods that convert QString to other types. QString is just a wrapper around a character string.

To get at the underlying char buffer you can do something like this:

```
std::string stdStr = qString.toStdString();
char* buffer = stdStr.c_str();
```

Make sure that `stdStr` stays in scope as long as you wish to use `buffer` otherwise you will end up using a pointer that points to deallocated memory.

Comment: Thanks. Now, since I want to use the QSerialPort module, I install it with "sudo apt-get install libqt5serialport5-dev". Restart Qt, but when I add "QT += serialport" to my .pro file, the bild fails, saying: "Unknown module(s) in Qt: serialport". Did I miss something? Thank you.